# Convergence of some series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that the series 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {|a_n|}^2$ is convergent .Which of the following statements are true ?

1. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$ is convergent
2. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {|a_n|}^p $ is convergent for all $2<p<\infty$
3. The series  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {|a_n|}^p $ is convergent for all
   $1<p<2$

Try 2 is true . Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {|a_n|}^2$ is convergent therefore
$a_n \to 0$ hence $a_n< 1$ for some $n\ge K$ hence 
${|a_n|}^p \le {|a_n|}^2$ for all $2<p<\infty$ therefore the series is convergent but the answer also say 1 is true along with 2 why?

Comment: Have you learned Cauchy-Schwartz inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

For $(1)$, use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality to establish that

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a_n}{n}\right)^2\le \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Please feel free to up vote this answer as you see fit of course.